# Multiple Inputs for neural network in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, input, neural-network

Im trying to implement a reinforcement learning algorithm with tensorflow to train an agent.

I want my neural network to have 2 different inputs, the first one an image stack of 4 images with the shape (4,160,120,1) and then just a one dimensional array with 10 entries.

I tried to do it like i did with just one input and defined my call function of my neural network with two inputs and ran my program. When the function train_on_batch was executed it resulted in an error and i received following message, in which states2 is my second input:

ValueError: Models passed to `train_on_batch` can only have `training` and the first argument in `call` as positional arguments, found: ['state2']

So how can I use two inputs for my neural network and still be able to use train_on_batch?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a model with two inputs something like

```
input1=tf.keras.Input( shape= .....
# add layers here to process input 1 as you wish 
# last layer should be a Flatten layer or GlobalMaxPooling Layer
out1=tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(previous layer)
input2= tf.keras.Input ( shape=....
add layers  to process input 2
# last layer should be a Flatten layer or GlobalMaxPooling Layer
out2=tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(previous layer)
# now concatenate the outputs out1 and out2
concatted = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate()([out1, out2])
# now you can add more layers here to process the concatted output as you wish
#  last layer should be your output layer
output=Dense (number of classes, activation='softmax;)(previous layer output)
model=keras.Model(inputs=[input1,input2], outputs=output)
#  then compile your model
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to either concatenate the inputs into a single npy array, or use a list of arrays, as stated [in the documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#train_on_batch) when running the `tf.keras.Model.train_on_batch()` function.